# How can I get the last transactions of an account from Horizon?

Tags: horizon

I need to retrieve the last 10 transactions (payments) of an account and I'm using the Horizon API, but the limit is 200 and I can't go beyond that. I explain you.
i'm using horizon.stellar.org/accounts/MYADDRESS/payments , but this only gives me the first 10....if i add ?limit=200 it gives me the first 200 but 200 is the maximum otherwise i get this error: `{'invalid_field ': 'limit', 'reason': 'invalid limit: value provided that is over limit max of 200'}}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a order parameter, so this will give you the 10 most recent transactions:
`https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/G.../transactions?order=desc&limit=10`

To walk through all transactions, pagination works with the cursor parameter so to get the second page you need to set `cursor=...` to the `paging_token` of the last transaction from the first page.